# use latest snapshot version from the remote repo

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

For now, I should to specify version explicitly:

```
  dependencies {

      compile 'projGroup:projName:0.1-SNAPSHOT'
  }
```

What's I've tried, but it doesn't work:

```
  compile "projGroup:projName:0.+-SNAPSHOT"
  compile "projGroup:projName:+"
```

How can I tell gradle to use latest **snapsot** version from the remote maven repo?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Verified with Gradle 2.2.1:

1. Override default 24h module caching in Gradle:

   ```
   configurations.all {
       resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
   }
   ```
2. Then, *latest.integration* will work with each Maven snapshot:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile 'projGroup:projName:latest.integration'
   }
   ```

Comment: The metadata rule `latest.release` is also available for release versions. This is described in the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html#component_metadata_rules).

Answer (score 5):

`compile "projGroup:projName:latest.integration"` should work.

Comment: In what way is it not working? By default, the cache timeout for snapshots is 24 hours, so you won't get a new snapshot before that.

Comment: I think that I asked the question not correctly. Sorry.
I have the repo with maven artifacts on github. All artifacts were created through uploadArchives task.
After adding url on the repo to the repositories I added to dependencies the line of code (compile 'projGroup:projName:0.1-SNAPSHOT') and it's works fine. But I don't want to specify the version explicitly, and the solution that you wrote doesn't work too. I've tried (compile "projGroup:projName:latest.integration").

Comment: Again, in what way does it not work? What is the exact and complete error message? Are you using a recent Gradle version?

Comment: Error:Could not find any version that matches projGroup:projName:latest.integration. I use gradle 1.8. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps try with a later version. If that doesn't work either, you'll likely have to stick to `0.1-SNAPSHOT`. That's also what you get when using Maven.