# How to get newest snapshot of a dependency without changing version in gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I build an own library that I deploy on a nexus repository. This snapshot is changed very often, therefore not every change gets a new version number. My problem is that I don't get the newest code without changing the version number in project that use this library. I tried "--refresh-dependencies" and I also tried to clear the dependency from the cache by deleting the folder of this dependency under "\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\my.dependency"
I also tried this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

Has anyone an idea how I can force grade to download the newest status of a dependency despite the version number didn't change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use latest snapshot version from the remote repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372508/use-latest-snapshot-version-from-the-remote-repo)

Comment: No, I tried this, but it didn't work. But I forgot to say that in my post. I'll edit it. 
}

Comment: For best results, you should include all relevant parts from your build script.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

First make sure your snapshot has the right version format:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: "groupId", name: "artifactId", version: "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

If you have not used the `-SNAPSHOT` suffix (or you are not using a Maven repository), you have to indicate that your dependency is changing:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: "groupId", name: "artifactId", version: "1.0", changing: true
}
```

Then you have to tell Gradle not to cache changing dependencies, otherwise it will only update them every 24 hours:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

In case you have also configured the dependency as a dynamic version like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: "groupId", name: "artifactId", version: "1+", changing: true
}
```

Then you have to add:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

Note that this might slow your build a lot.

If this doesn't help, remove the relevant parts of `.gradle` directory, or simply the whole directory again.

If that doesn't help neither, I am afraid it will be an issue on your repository side.

Comment: Ok deleting the .gradle directory worked. But actually this wasn't the solution I was looking for. I thought gradle would offer possibilities to do that by build.gradle. Okay, but better than nothing.

Comment: @Thunderforge true, I should update the answer. Next time feel free to edit it to fix any misconceptions, thanks.

Comment: In the last code block, is there some reason that `cacheChangingModulesFor` is in seconds, but `cacheDynamicVersionsFor` is in minutes? Or can you use either time unit?

Comment: @Thunderforge the only reason is that I was copying it from existing scripts. You can use any units: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

Comment: @n00bst3r  check your repositories config. The mavenLocal() needs to be below your internal repo manager to find the update snapshot.

Comment: In above answer this line (or you are not using a Maven repository), so will it not work for non-maven repository? We are using jfrog artifactory and following the convention of :0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, but still gradle picks from cache and not latest. any solution?

Comment: i'm having the same issue with Jfrog repository

Comment: Use commandline arg --refresh-dependencies,  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dynamic_versions.html

gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies

Comment: For me, every time reopening the project then dependencies refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
./gradlew --refresh-dependencies run
```

to start the application and refresh all dependencies.

Source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dynamic_versions.html (via a comment above by [@Dmitriy Pichugin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1689489/dmitriy-pichugin)).

> The --refresh-dependencies option tells Gradle to ignore all cached entries for resolved modules and artifacts.